# filter an interface or type by property types

Tags: typescript

I have this `type`

```
type Obj = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  birth: Date;
  weight: number;
  height: number;
}
```

I want to filter Obj whose properties extend `number | string`, namely I want to get

```
type Filtered = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  weight: number;
  height: number;
}
```

I looked up Typescript utility types, but none satisfied my needs. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a helper that finds properties based on their values:

```
type PropertyOfValue<T, V> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V
    ? K
    : never
}[keyof T];
```

Now we can find the properties we're looking for by doing and pick them from the source object:

```
type Filtered = Pick<Obj, PropertyOfValue<Obj, string | number>>
```

**Bonus**

If you like, you can abstract the pattern of picking by value and put it in the global namespace.

```
declare global {
  namespace Pick {
    type ByValue<T, U> = Pick<T, PropertyOfValue<T, U>>
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
type Filtered = Pick.ByValue<Obj, string | number>
```